# T-SQL with IF logic not working with temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#iftry') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #iftry

IF OBJECT_ID('BIC_Analytics.dbo.AdjudicateAllDCCharteredClaims') IS  NULL
begin
select 'this is start of first block'
 SELECT 'this is first block' as blockid
 INTO #iftry
select 'this is end of first block'
end

ELSE

begin
select 'this is start of 2nd block'
 SELECT 'this is 2nd block' as blockid
    INTO #iftry
select 'this is end of 2nd block'
end

select ':)'

select * from #iftry
```

Keeps giving me the error:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
There is already an object named '#iftry' in the database.
```

Now it works

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#iftry') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #iftry

create table #iftry (blockid varchar(20))


IF OBJECT_ID('BIC_Analytics.dbo.AdjudicateAllDCCharteredClaims') IS NOT NULL
begin
--select 'this is start of first block'
 insert into #iftry (blockid)
 select 'this is first block' 
--select 'this is end of first block'
end

ELSE

begin
--select 'this is start of 2nd block'
 insert into #iftry (blockid)
 select 'this is 2nd block' 
--select 'this is end of 2nd block'
end

select ':)'

select * from #iftry
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a parsing problem, not a runtime problem. SQL Server can't see that there are two code paths that can't be reached.

To work around it, create your #temp table once up front:

```
SELECT 'bogus' INTO #iftry
  WHERE 1 = 0; -- creates empty table

IF ...
  INSERT #iftry ...
ELSE ...
  INSERT #iftry ...
```

There's no way to tell SQL Server not to work this way unless you put the two #table declarations in separate batches (which you can't really do), or build dynamic SQL and work with the #temp table at that scope (not fun).