# IF Exists doesn't work properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help with this query, I'm trying to run it but all I keep getting is

```
"There is already an object named '#PreFixedData1' in the database."
```

Can you please advise on a workaround so that the data will go in by using the nested IF Exists statement ? I've also tried using an `ELSE IF EXISTS` after the first `IF EXISTS` but I get the same error.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PostPivotTbl (
TestDate VARCHAR(100)
 );

 GO

INSERT INTO dbo.PostPivotTbl
VALUES ('17/Jul/2014'),
'10/May/2014' ) 



IF EXISTS (
SELECT TestDate
FROM dbo.PostPivotTbl
WHERE TestDate LIKE '[1-9]%' AND TestDate NOT LIKE '0%' AND TestDate NOT LIKE '%/%'
  )

BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PreFixedData1', 'u') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #PreFixedData1

 SELECT
 CAST(TestDate AS INT) AS 'TestDate'
 INTO #PreFixedData1
 FROM dbo.PostPivotTbl

 END

 ELSE

    BEGIN


      IF EXISTS(

             SELECT TestDate
             FROM dbo.PostPivotTbl
             WHERE TestDate 
  LIKE '%2013%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%' OR TestDate LIKE '%2014%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%' 

  OR
        TestDate LIKE '%2013%' AND TestDate LIKE '%/%' OR TestDate LIKE '%2014%' AND      
        TestDateLIKE '%/%'   
   OR TestDate LIKE '%2012%' AND TestDate LIKE '%/%'
   OR
TestDate LIKE '%Jan%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%Feb%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%Mar%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%Apr%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%May%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%Jun%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%Jul%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%Aug%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%Sep%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%Oct%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%Nov%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
OR
TestDate LIKE '%Dec%' AND TestDate LIKE '%-%'
)

BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PreFixedData1', 'u') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #PreFixedData1


SELECT
CAST(TestDate AS DATETIME) AS 'TestDate'
INTO #PreFixedData1
FROM dbo.PostPivotTbl

    END
END
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I conditionally create a table in Sybase (TSQL)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307942/how-do-i-conditionally-create-a-table-in-sybase-tsql)

Comment: or possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408599/t-sql-with-if-logic-not-working-with-temp-table?rq=1)

Comment: @ninesided - No it's not, that guy's issue is different, he's unable to create a table, I am creating the table, just can't query from it once the data is in...

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing to do with the `EXISTS` clause (which looks very messy by the way), it is to do with the way SQL Server compiles the statements. You can recreate this simply with:

```
IF 1 = 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT Col = 1
    INTO #T;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT Col = 2
    INTO #T;
END
```

Which gives the error:

> There is already an object named '#T' in the database.

Even though only one branch of the IF statement can every be followed, SQL Server compiles them both, so when it compiles the second branch it estabilishes that `#T` will exists, so throws a compilation error.

The work arround is to create the table once, and use `INSERT [Table] SELECT..`:

```
CREATE TABLE #PreFixedData1 (TestDateInt INT, TestDate DATETIME);

IF ...
    INSERT #PreFixedData1 (TestDateInt)
    SELECT ....

ELSE 
    INSERT #PreFixedData1 (TestDate)
    SELECT ...
```

It is beyond the scope of the question, but I have no idea why you would create a column that is `VARCHAR(100)` and then insert dates to it. Keep dates and dates then you don't need to do all sorts of bizarre comparisons to work out if it is a valid date. I am also not sure why you want to conditionally create the same table but with a different datatype for the column depending on the data in the table.

As a further aside, using [string literals as column aliases is on the deprecation list](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) (`SELECT Column AS 'Alias'`)

Comment: I am trying to find a different way to cast data types that would originally come from an excel file which would have datetime columns in VARCHAR or NVARCHAR, this is a way to counteract the precedence data types issue that I came across last week. By the way, I see you're in Manchester like me :D cool stuff, also I'll try your solution now and let you know how it goes, thanks.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Worked a treat mate, modified your solution a bit but it did work, thanks for the tip !

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: No worries. If you were using SQL Server 2012, I would have suggested the `TRY_CONVERT` function, then all the checking would have been redundant. Oh well, if you have managed to get to a working solution that is good enough for me.